# Python json encode dictionary value for API

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

Python beginner here;

I have a CSV file which has come from Excel. I would like to parse the entries into JSON strings for use with an API of an internal application.

The script uses two For loops, one to read entries from the CSV and add them into a Dictionary, the second substitutes data from the dictionary entries into a  template string which is correctly formatted for API requests by converting to a JSON string.

This is an example of a populated dictionary entry - the format corresponds to the API specification;

```
{'description': 'Mrs Davies 7M3/It', 'resourceId': '16', 'userId': 26, 'accessories': [], 'startReminder': '', 'recurrenceRule': {'monthlyType': 'null', 'interval': 2, 'type': 'weekly', 'weekdays': [1], 'repeatTerminationDate': '2016-05-29T08:50:00'}, 'title': 'Mrs Davies 7M3/It', 'resourceID': '16', 'endDateTime': '2016\xad02\xad22T10:50:00', 'participants': [], 'customAttributes': [], 'endReminder': '', 'startDateTime': '2016\xad02\xad22T09:50:00', 'resources': ['16'], 'invitees': []}
```

As you can see the startDataTime and endDateTime has a hex value for the hyphen symbol.

```
'endDateTime': '2016\xad02\xad22T10:50:00'
```

If I pass this value as a variable (tempData) as below;

```
res_data = json.dumps(tempData)
```

I get the error;

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "api.py", line 70, in <module>
           res_data = json.dumps(tempData) 
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
           return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
           chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
           return _iterencode(o, 0)
         UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 4: invalid start byte
```

The script has been working up until now with no problem. I've tried to re-encode the data as it's being parsed through json.dumps but doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to encode the data into utf8 from within the dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you get data from the source which has encoding 'Cp1252' 
You can have dictionary as

```
data = {1:2, 'endDateTime': '2016\xad02\xad22T10:50:00'.decode('cp1252')}
json.dump(data)
'{"1": 2, "endDateTime": "2016\\u00ad02\\u00ad22T10:50:00"}'
```

If you are not very sure about the encoding type and already have dictionary with such string then you can ask json to take care of it-

```
json.dumps({'endDateTime': '2016\xad02\xad22T10:50:00'}, ensure_ascii=False)
# It prints '{"endDateTime": "2016\xad02\xad22T10:50:00"}'
```

Your code should work with below change

```
res_data = json.dumps(tempData, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough I had that before but didn't do anything. I've added it and now the JSON string is being created but I have an additional error which is probably my data.